# Non-preemptive scheduing. Shortest job first

Tags: multiprocessing, cpu, computer-science, scheduling

The first process is very long but arrives first with nothing else in the queue so that the CPU will process this. I know in nonpreemptive scheduling you cannot interrupt and then resume a process however could I terminate the first process when the shorter process arrives and then restart the process all over again to reduce wait time?

For example

P1=-50 burst time  arrival time -0

P2 -5 burst time  arrival time -10

P3 -10 burst time arrival time -20

Could I terminate P1, start P2 and then P3, and then restart the whole of P1 to reduce wait time?

I have tried looking online and I can't seem to understand the answer

Comment: (The way the tag is described 2023/02, [tag:multiprocessing] does not pertain.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your needs here is that you need to preempt a process (P1) in a non-preemptive environment. The whole point of a non-preemptive scheduling scheme is to prevent exactly what you want to do.

Here are some hints to solve your problem:

- Have a periodic routine in P1 that checks if P2 (or P3) is ready. If it is the case, let terminate P1 itself (calling exit for instance). The frequency of this routine will define the reactivity (latency) of the system to execute P2 or P3. Once P2 terminate, before its termination, you could check if you have more work to do. If not, P2 can ask the system to start executing P1 again (calling exec for instance).
- Switch to a priority based scheduler, what you seem to need is to execute short processes first, thus I would go with RM scheduling (Rate Monotonic) which executes processes based on their worst case execution time. In that case, some scheduling schemes perform better (EDF for instance). This solution would have the advantage that P1 does not have to start from scratch but resume its execution.